# Where was Tony Stark born?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

I have just learned that [Tony Stark was born on Long Island,](http://marvel.com/universe/Iron_Man_(Anthony_Stark)) but I haven't been able to find any information about [where on Long Island](http://marvel.wikia.com/Iron_Man_(Anthony_%22Tony%22_Stark)) he was born.

Long Island is, as the name suggests, fairly long (over a hundred miles long, and about 20 to 30 miles wide).  Roughly 7.6 million people live there, although about half of them live in Brooklyn and Queens, which are geographically part of LI, but politically part of New York City.

[image]

As a native Long Islander myself, I am certain that Stark was born in either Suffolk or Nassau county, rather than Brooklyn or Queens.  If they meant Queens or Brooklyn, they would have either named them specifically, or simply said "New York City".  People who actually live in NYC are quite vocal about the difference between NYC and LI, and although Long Islanders like to say that we're from "New York", we know full well that we're fudging the details when we do so (our greatest fear is to try the "I'm from New York" trick on someone, only to find out that the other person is *really* from NYC).  The point is this:  while it might seem to outsiders that "Tony Stark was born on Long Island" could mean he's from NYC *or* Nassau/Suffolk, anyone who is from the area knows that it can only be the latter.

Is there any information about what town, or at least what county, Tony Stark was born in?

*Bonus question:  Tony's parents were killed on Long Island as well - do we know where it happened?*

Comment: In the heart of a dying star

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Film Universe:

According to his personnel file from the recent Avengers film, Tony was born in **Manhattan, New York**, not Long Island.

[image]

### Comic Universe

<s>His family certainly maintained [extensive holdings](http://marvel.wikia.com/Stark_Industries_(Earth-616)) on the shores of Long Island Sound. I see no good reason why someone with a "Multi-Billion Dollar Estate" would go to a public hospital to have a baby.</s>

It has since been revealed that Tony was...

> [secretly adopted](http://marvel.wikia.com/Anthony_Stark_(Earth-616)#Adoption) and that his birthplace was in a hospital near Sofia, Bulgaria.
>  [image]
>  <sub><sup>[International Iron Man #5](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/55544/international_iron_man_2016_5)</sup></sub>

Comment: I upvoted it.  Don't ask me.  For what it's worth, some of the hospitals on the North Shore of Nassau County are quite posh.  Long Island Jewish Hospital is one of the finest in the country.

Comment: I also upvoted...seems weird to downvote this.  I imagine some of the hospitals around Stony Brook are not only pretty classy, but also quite advanced in the level of care and types of treatments offered (by being affiliated to the university).

Comment: @Praxis - And they get lots of practice treating cancer because of all the hazardous chemical leaks in the area.

Comment: @Richard - Oddly, the page you linked says that (1) Tony Stark was adopted, and (2) he was born on Long Island.

Comment: @wadCheber - I think it should say that his papers were doctored to say Long Island, presumably because it's easier to say he was a home birth (and get a single doctor to lie on the birth certificate) than to get all the doctors and nurses at a hospital to lie.

Comment: @Richard - **IRON MAN WAS BORN DOWN THE STREET FROM MY HOUSE AND I WON'T LET YOU TAKE THAT AWAY FROM ME!**

Comment: @wadCheber - He might still be

Comment: The updated page you linked says he was born in Sofia, Bulgaria.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Yes, additional canon info has been revealed...

Comment: Bulgaria... 'cuz why not. Actually, I'm pretty sure that the writers picked Sofia, Bulgaria using a world map and some darts.